# Add Free Promotional Gift for purchase of more than 200$ and different gift after more than $380 from same category

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, free-gift

I want to run the Christmas promo on site. I have to promote the gifts after purchase of 200$ and $380 respectively.

- If someone buy a products more than **$200**, I want to give a free gift product **Sports Band**.
- If someone buy a products more than **$380**, I want to give a free gift product **Sports Belt**.

If they purchased the products from "Sports" category.

**In other words:**

1. Sport Category Products Total more than $200

   => Free Sport Band
2. Sport Category Products Total more than $380

   => Free Sport Belt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks,

For your reply. I have found the solution , i'm new in magento so find out the solution to add the free gift and i have tested many extensions but no one worked properly. The extension i was looking it was paid andy near about $130, so i have save money and time with this extension>

> [S3i Business Gift Promo](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/s3i-business-gift-promo.html)

It is very good extension and fulfill my requirement. Thanks for this greatfull extension.

Thanks all of you for reply and support

Answer (score 5):

There is a lightweight free extension for exactly this scenario: [C4B_FreeProduct](https://github.com/code4business/freeproduct)

It adds a new shopping cart price rules action "free product" where you can enter qty and sku.

[image: screenshot admin]

These products are added to the cart as non editable items with price 0 during sales rule validation.

[image: screenshot cart]

#### Configuration

You would create two shopping cart price rules with conditions like this:

[image]

And then configure the "Add a gift" action.

#### How it works

- A new rule type is added to the sales rule form, in an observer on `adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform`
- An observer on `salesrule_validator_process` processes the new rule type. It adds the configured SKU to the cart and sets a custom price of 0 and a custom option that identifies the product as free gift.
- Another observer on `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` removes existing gift items from the cart (that's what the custom option from before is for), before the rules are processed.
- The cart item template is adjusted to remove qty input and "remove" link from gift items (they would not work anyways).

***Disclaimer: I was involved in the development of this extension.***

Answer (score 2):

Make a new observer on event

```
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
```

then simply check the product price and which category it belongs to.